# Should I indent all assignment statements so that all "=" signs come in the same line?

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style, indentation

Some of my colleagues follow this indentation style, where they add spaces/tabs before and after each `=` operator in assignment statements. They even do this even if there is only one assignment statement in the block. I'm all in for writing readable, beautiful code. But is this kind of alignment throughout the file really required?

Sample code to demonstrate this kind of indentation is given below.

```
    public function getCMSSectionData($args="1")
    {
        $sql                    =   "SELECT * FROM     med_cms_section WHERE $args";            
        $data                   =   $this->getdbcontents_sql($sql); 
        return $data;
    }

    public function insertCMSSection($dataArray)
    {

        $sendCount  =   100;

        $sql        =   "select * from med_email_pending order by priority desc limit ".$sendCount;
        $res        =   $this->db_query($sql);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $id         =   $row["id"];
            $to         =   $row["to"];
            $from       =   $row["from"];
            $subject    =   $row["subject"];
            $message    =   $row["message"];
            $priority   =   $row["priority"];
            $this->sendmail($to,$from,$subject,$message);
            $this->sendmail("user@example.com",$from,$subject,$message);
            $sql        =   "delete from med_email_pending where id=".$id;
            $this->db_query($sql);
        }
    }
```

Isn't this:-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM med_cms_section WHERE $args";         
$data = $this->getdbcontents_sql($sql);
```

better than this:-

```
$sql                    =   "SELECT * FROM med_cms_section WHERE $args";            
$data                   =   $this->getdbcontents_sql($sql);
```

Comment: No, this is not required, at least not in PHP. It's also quite ugly when over-used.

Comment: This is completely optional. I have a lot of code that doesn't indent after `=`, and some code where it actually makes it more clear.

Comment: In `getCMSSectionData`, the distance of indent seems completely arbitrary. So you're not really asking, "please tell my colleagues that they are wrong to line up their `=` signs", you're asking "please tell my colleagues that they're wrong to insert arbitrary amounts of whitespace that push their line length over 80 characters". Beware of accidentally presenting a straw man argument.

Answer (score 2):

No. It makes code alterations more difficult (you have to manually align.. unless your IDE does this for you) and I don't think it makes code any more readable. Perhaps that is subjective though.

Comment: Again subjectively, I think it *occasionally* makes code more readable. In cases where you want to be able to see where two or more lines are the same and where they differ, having them lined up does help somewhat. But those cases are rare, certainly not worth mutilating the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's a horrible idea for at least one reason. If you need to add a row, you might need to reformat several other rows. This confuses your diff viewer when you want to see what changes was made between revisions in source control.